# How to configure Pentaho Carte to accept HTTPS request instead of HTTP

Tags: ssl, https, pentaho, kettle

I have a requirement where Pentaho Carte server needs to accept "HTTPS" instead of the default "HTTP".

I have followed the following link but to no avail:

https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.0/0L0/0Y0/060/060/010#Configuring_Carte_Servers_for_SSL

Following are the steps I followed:

1. Using the Keytool I created a `.jks` file using the following command:

   ```
   keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore   C:\KEY_STORE\Pentaho\keystore.jks -storepass password -validity 360 -keysize 2048
   ```
2. I edited the `carte_config_master-8080.xml` file on my system which now looks as:

   ```
   <slaveserver>
       <name>master1</name>
       <hostname>10.67.110.93</hostname>
       <port>8080</port>
       <master>Y</master>
       <sslConfig>
           <keyStore>C:\KEY_STORE\Pentaho</keyStore>
           <keyStorePassword>password</keyStorePassword>
           <keyPassword>password</keyPassword>
       </sslConfig>
   </slaveserver>
   ```

   As can be seen I have created the `.jks` file and mentioned its location in `carte-config-master-8080.xml`.
3. I am invoking Carte as:

   ```
   C:\software\pdi-ce-5.4.0.1-130\data-integration>Carte.bat carte-config-master-8080.xml
   DEBUG: Using PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME
   DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
   DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
   ```
4. Carte is getting invoked but it is not accepting "HTTPS", I guess because of following error:

   ```
   validation.properties could not be loaded by any means. fail. Exception was: java.lang.IllegalArgume
   classloader resource.
   SecurityConfiguration for Logger.LogServerIP not either "true" or "false" in ESAPI.properties. Using
   2017/02/02 15:33:31 - Carte - Using SSL mode
   2017/02/02 15:33:31 - Carte - Created listener for webserver @ address : 10.67.110.93:8080
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
           at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\KEY_STORE\Pentaho (Access is denied)
           at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
           at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
   ```

   It can be clearly seen that the folder where the key is saved is inaccessible. I have given full access rights to the folder.

P.S. - Working on Pentaho Kettle Community Edition 5.4 & Windows 7

Any suggestions?

Comment: just recently has been raised same topic. how to configure jetty to use https

Comment: @simar - sadly, no substantial response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is a mistake in documentation.

line

```
<keyStore>C:\KEY_STORE\Pentaho</keyStore>
```

Documentaion states

```
keyStore  | Path to the keystore **file**.  | Yes
```

Important part is **"...file..."**

Try to replace with

```
<keyStore>C:\KEY_STORE\Pentaho\keystore.jks</keyStore>
```

And as well i would prefer to use backslash

```
<keyStore>C:/KEY_STORE/Pentaho/keystore.jks</keyStore>
```

Comment: It got resolve. @Simar, thanks for your time. One more point, it might help someone in future, is Jetty's default port is not 8010, rather 8443.

Comment: Tomcat and Jetty has several ports normally used. I know, usually 8080 reserved for http, 8443 for https as well there is port used to send message to shutdown the server or to identify that instance already running during start.

Comment: Actually a lots of ports possibly configured on server using connectors, like jms, in memory database, ajp protocol support and so on.